# Sequelize - one foreign key to multiple related tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a many-to-many table that I'm using to dynamically join several child tables to a single parent. Using Postgres 13 and latest Sequelize.

> parent_table -> join_table -> child_1, child_2, child_3

The join table model looks like this:

```
const joinTableModel = {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    parent_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: false,
        allowNull: false
    },
    related_record_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: false,
        allowNull: false
    },
    related_type: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),    
        allowNull: false
    }
};
```

A child table would look like this:

```
const childExampleModel = {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    title: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
        allowNull: false
    },
    //...etc...
};
```

It's built this way in an attempt to get around adding hard-coded keys to any of the related tables, for a very specific edge case. Not looking to redesign it unless this is impossible in Sequelize.

Naturally, you can query this all day in SQL but Sequelize seems to be choking on the relationships when creating foreign keys.

I need all of the child tables to join to the parent, through the join table, from the join table's related_record_id to each child's primary key.

To clarify: parent.id = join.parent_id, join.related_record_id = child.id

I've tried this:

```
parent.belongsToMany(child1, { through: join_table, foreignKey: "related_record_id" });
child1.belongsToMany(parent, { through: join_table, foreignKey: "related_record_id" });

parent.belongsToMany(child2, { through: join_table, foreignKey: "related_record_id" });
child2.belongsToMany(parent, { through: join_table, foreignKey: "related_record_id" });
```

...which has really weird behavior. It does both but child2 "wins" and there's no FK constraint to child1 - only child2. If I comment out the bottom two lines, child1 is the winner. I assume it has something to do with the generic way Sequelize builds the fk constraints? It's like the first one is "overwritten".

Seems pretty straightforward to me - how does this work in Sequelize?

**UPDATE**:

Not a lot of traction on this, so here's a SQL demo of what I am trying to do:

```
--build it
create table parent (
    id int primary key not null,
    name varchar(20) not null
);

create table child1 (
    id int primary key not null,
    name varchar(20) not null
);

create table child2 (
    id int primary key not null,
    name varchar(20) not null
);

create table child_to_parent (
    parent_id int not null,
    child_id int not null,
    child_type varchar(20)
);

insert into child1 (id, name) values (1, 'child_1-1');
insert into child1 (id, name) values (2, 'child_1-2');

insert into child2 (id, name) values (1, 'child_2-1');
insert into child2 (id, name) values (2, 'child_2-2');

insert into parent (id, name) values (1, 'parent record');

insert into child_to_parent (parent_id, child_id, child_type) values (1, 1, 'child1');
insert into child_to_parent (parent_id, child_id, child_type) values (1, 2, 'child1');
insert into child_to_parent (parent_id, child_id, child_type) values (1, 1, 'child2');
insert into child_to_parent (parent_id, child_id, child_type) values (1, 2, 'child2');

alter table child_to_parent add constraint fk_child1_to_parent foreign key (child_id) references child1 (id);
alter table child_to_parent add constraint fk_child2_to_parent foreign key (child_id) references child2 (id);

--query it
select
    p.id,
    p.name,
    c2p.child_type,
    c1.name,
    c2.name
from
    parent p
left join
    child_to_parent c2p
    on c2p.parent_id = p.id
left join
    child1 c1
    on c1.id = c2p.child_id
left join
    child2 c2
    on c2.id = c2p.child_id
where
    c2p.child_type = 'child1'
```

Comment: If I correctly understand what you are after then *you **cannot** do it*. A FK column can only reference 1 table, every row references the same table. What you are attempting violates this. Sequelize cannot generate it because it cannot exist in Postgres (or any other RDBMS). What you say is *really weird behavior* is the requirement. Your choices: 1-Add a column for each child table to the resolution table.(doable but bad idea). 2-Change data model to a 1:M for each child and create a FK in each to the parent.  Multiple  1:M relationships is not hard coding nor duplication.

Comment: @Belayer Please see my update for an example.